# Select data from the same the column that meets two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table 1 with data :

```
+----+---------+-------+
| ID | GenreID | Title |
+----+---------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | Fox   |
|  2 |      12 | Fox   |
|  3 |       1 | Cat   |
|  4 |       4 | Cat   |
|  5 |       1 | Lion  |
|  6 |      12 | Lion  |
|  6 |       3 | Tiger |
|  5 |      12 | Tiger |
+----+---------+-------
```

How can I get the Title that has both GenreID = 1 and 12?

My desired results are to return the title: `Fox` and `Lion`. But if I use `IN` the result is: `fox`, `lion`, `cat`, `tiger`

Comment: What do you want as the desired result?  `OR` is going to return the `Cat` even though it doesn't have `12` as an `GenreID`.  Is that the expected result? Or do you want to return only the `Title` that has both `GenreIDs`?

Comment: @bluefeet: My desired results: return Title : Fox and Lion .

But if I use IN , Or => result : fox , lion, cat, tiger ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to return the rows that have both `GenreId = 1` **AND** `GenreID = 12`, you have to use some relational division. The query will use the `IN` clause to return the rows that have the `GenreIDs` that you want but you'll also use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to filter out the rows that have both:

```
select title
from yourtable
where genreid in (1, 12)
group by title
having count(distinct genreid) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa49e/1). This returns `Fox` and `Lion`.  The `HAVING` clause counts the distinct number of `GenreIDs` that are returned. In this case you want that to be equal to 2, the total number of IDs included in your WHERE clause.

There are many different ways that you can get the result, including skipping the `WHERE` clause and use an aggregate function and some conditional logic in a HAVING:

```
select title
from yourtable
group by title
having sum(case when GenreID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
  and sum(case when GenreID = 12 then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa49e/5)

Comment: @LCIII Care to explain?

Comment: Sure. And that wasn't meant to be a slight on your creative answer. Maybe kludgey wasn't the right word seeing as you are correct answering his question, but you're doing it based on the *number* of conditions and not the conditions themselves.

Comment: @LCIII I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @LCII Now this can be called kludgey (and classic at the same time): [`select distinct title from yourtable t1 where not exists (select 1 from yourtable t2 where t2.genreid in (1, 12) and not exists (select 1 from yourtable t3 where t3.genreid = t2.genreid and t3.title = t1.title)) ;`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa49e/13)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT title from [tab] where GenreId = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT title from [tab] where GenreId = 12
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer.